# Indicate message status in chat using android

Tags: java, android, firebase, chat

I'm developing a chat application in android using firebase and my own database.

This is my database structure:

```
id    | text     | user    | time       | seen  | conversation_id
__________________________________________________________________
1     | Hi!      | 8       | 1567443254 | 0     | 1
```

In seen column, **0** means **delivered** and **1** means message **seen**.

So for indicating message status, I tried to get the whole data in every second and set a new adapter to existing RecyclerView.

It works and update the messages status every second but there is a problem, when it loads the new data, RecyclerView's scroll changes and I also tried `.notifyDataSetChanged()` and that changes the scroll position too.

I think technically this is not the right way. Is there better suggestion to do this?

Comment: Please add your database structure which is for sure not structured as tables and the code that you are using.

Comment: @AlexMamo "my own database", so we can't know whether that is a relational or NoSQL database. :)

Comment: @Daniel: it will be hard to comment on your current implementation without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the situation you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you're right. Btw, congras for your Google I/O'19 speech :)